# JSON decoder TypeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swiftui

typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "current_page", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct URLImage: View {
    let urlString: String
    
    @State var data: Data?
    
    var body: some View{
        
        if let data = data, let uiimage = UIImage(data: data) {
            Image(uiImage: uiimage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                    .background(Color.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(3)
        }
        else{
            
        Image(systemName: "video")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .onAppear{
                    fetchData()
                }
              }
    }
    
    private func fetchData(){
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, _,
            _ in
            self.data = data
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List{
                ForEach(viewModel.travels){ travel in
                    HStack {
                        URLImage(urlString: travel.description)
                                            
                            Text("\(travel.name)")
                                    .bold()
                        
                            }
                            .padding(10)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Travels")
            .onAppear{
                viewModel.fetch()
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

ViewModel

```
struct Travel : Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let image_url : String
    let description: String
    let positive_votes_count: String
}

class ViewModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var travels: [Travel] = []
    
    func fetch() {
        guard let url = URL (string: "https://api.500px.com/v1/photos?feature=popular&page=1")
        else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ [weak self] data, _ ,
            error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            do{
                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [Travel]].self, from: data)
                            
                            if let travels = response["photos"] {
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self?.travels = travels
                                }
                            }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
           
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to decode it so that it can be displayed on a ContentView page.

Comment: `image_url` is an array, not a single item.

Comment: I'm trying to understand now. since I am a complete novice. I appreciate your assistance, but I don't get what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access the `[Travel]` array this way. You have to add a struct for the root object.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let photos : [Travel]
}
```

and change `Travel` to

```
struct Travel : Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int // not String
    let name: String
    let image_url : [URL] // or [String] but not String
    let description: String
    let positive_votes_count: Int // not String 
}
```

Then decode

```
let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.travels = response.photos
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for it. I'm going to go back and get a better understanding of data types. And I can see how this could be problematic. Many thanks for it.